# Having a CSS class selector override a CSS id selector

Tags: jquery, class, layout, animation, html

I am trying to get a css class selector to override an id selector... the reason I wan't to do this is because I am trying to create a jQuery website design that has boxes on the left, when these boxes are clicked, any open box minimises and the one clicked opens... The boxes are denoted by an id such as for the nth box `id="box_n"` and when a box is opened it is given the class `"selected"` so it can be seen by the jQuery as the box that needs to be minimised when another box is selected. However i want the selected boxes to be scrollable, and therefore the `"selected"` class needs to override the `"box_n"` id scroll attribute which is set to `scroll:hidden`. Is there any way of doing this simply? Here is the css that I have...

```
.selected
{
overflow: scroll;
}

#box_1
{
background-color:#000;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0.6;
top: 0px;
left: -100px;
margin-right:auto;
float: left;
height: 65px;
width: 135px;
border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
overflow:hidden;
}
```

and the jQuery is here:

```
$("#box_3")
    .animate({
        width: largeWidth,
        left: 60,
        top: 0,
        borderRadius: 10,
        MozborderRadius: 10
    }, (60), "swing")
    .animate({
        height: largeHeight
    }, (60), "swing")
    .animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, (160));

$("#box_3").addClass("selected");
selected = 1;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `!important` on your rules. It will make them override anything else.

```
.selected
{
    overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: Aha new there would be a simple fix! thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.selected
{
overflow: scroll!important;
}
```

This will add to the weight of the overflow parameter on the .selected box.

Comment: I think you're missing a space before the `!important`, aren't you?

Comment: funny thing is, I never put the space before "!important". Has always worked for me. Is the space optional or have the browsers been tolerant to me so far?

Comment: Worth a look in the specs, I'll check when I'm next to my PC